# Fancybox gallery groups

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm using fancybox http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/, and my question is:

Could i group different resources together? I mean images with inline or video in the same gallery (or 'group'). If yes, anyone knows how?

Here an example that doesn't work:

```
<a class="fancyinline" data-fancybox-group="testgroup" href="#cont3">Test</a>
<div class="fancyhidden" id="cont3">Test Content</div>
<a class="fancyimage" data-fancybox-group="testgroup" href="test.jpg" >
    <img src="test-th.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
```

fancyinline and fancyimage aren't grouped together, but I need so.
Of course I need different parameters for inlines and images...

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 13):

To group elements for navigation inside the fancybox, you need to set the `rel` attribute on each on them.
The same `rel` value will tell fancybox that all of them are to be present to navigation if one gets open.

See this [working Fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/wm8QD/)

## GROUP EXAMPLE

**HTML**

```
<a rel="example_group" title="Custom title" href="full_path_to_image.jpg">
  <img alt="" src="path_to_image_thumbs.jpg">
</a>
<a rel="example_group" title="Custom title" href="full_path_to_image.jpg">
  <img alt="" src="path_to_image_thumbs.jpg">
</a>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$("a[rel=example_group]").fancybox();
```

---

## GROUP EXAMPLE ONE VISIBLE, REST HIDDEN

**HTML**

```
<a rel="group2" title="Custom title" href="full_path_to_image.jpg">
  <img alt="" src="path_to_image_thumbs.jpg">
</a>
<a rel="group2" title="" href="full_path_to_img.jpg" style="display:none;"></a>
<a rel="group2" title="" href="full_path_to_img.jpg" style="display:none;"></a>
<a rel="group2" title="" href="full_path_to_img.jpg" style="display:none;"></a>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$("a[rel=group2]").fancybox();
```

Comment: I know this, it works for image-groups.
I need 'heterogeneous' groups (images, video or inlines all in the same group).
I'va added an example on my post.

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this

```
$("#fancybox-manual-c").click(function() {
            $.fancybox.open([
                {
                    href : '1_b.jpg',
                    title : 'My title'
                }, {
                    href : '2_b.jpg',
                    title : '2nd title'
                }, {
                    href : '3_b.jpg'
                }
            ], {
                helpers : {
                    thumbs : {
                        width: 75,
                        height: 50
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```