# fancybox arrows not showing due to position

Tags: jquery, html, css, fancybox, fancybox-2

I'm trying to add a fancybox gallery system to a website I'm currently working on, but the arrows won't show up. The images are in the same folder as my css file (and as you can see the closing button appears). The images are in the same group so that's not the problem either. I think it's a problem with the position of the arrows, but I've tried changing everything with Firebug and nothing makes a difference. You can see a demo [here](http://aurelienbudynek.citydeallovers.com/photos.php).

PS: The white border around the images also won't show up. I don't know if this is in any way related?

Answer (score 0):

Did you use `rel="group"` on `<a>` elements ?

Otherwise, you can add this CSS :

```
.fancybox-prev span {
    left: 10px;
    background-position: 0 -36px;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    top: 0;
    display: block;
}
.fancybox-next span {
        right: 10px;
        background-position: 0 -36px;
        width: 32px;
        height: 32px;
        top: 0;
        display: block;
 }
```

And then position it where you wants.

See this post on SO about groups images : 
[Fancybox gallery groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10676588/fancybox-gallery-groups)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. Turns out the problem was I was using an older version of Fancybox somewhere else on this website and they were interfering -_-